# Make this Responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, responsive

i'm asking help for make responsive this vid and text code.
On desktop version i'm seeing this correctly, on mobile text is too big and cover other section and vid is not sized correctly (too big), for look at it in right way i have to reduce zoom from 100% to 50%.
How could i fix this?

```css
.main-banner {
  position: relative;
}

#bg-video {
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100vh;
  object-fit: cover;
  z-index: -1;
}

#bg-video::-webkit-media-controls {
  display: none !important;
}

.video-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgba(35, 45, 57, 0.8);
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 7px;
  width: 100%;
}

.main-banner .caption {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  width: 80%;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.main-banner .caption h6 {
  margin-top: 0px;
  font-size: 22px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 800;
  color: #fff;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
}

.main-banner .caption h2 {
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  font-size: 57px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 800;
  color: #fff;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.main-banner .caption h2 em {
  font-style: normal;
  color: #ff0000;
  font-weight: 900;
}

.main-banner .caption h2 strong {
  font-style: normal;
  color: black;
  font-weight: 900;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-banner" id="top">
  <video autoplay muted loop id="bg-video">
            <source src="assets/images/gym-video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
        </video>

  <div class="video-overlay header-text">
    <div class="caption">
      <h6></h6>
      <h2>Senza motivazione non c'è <em>sacrificio</em>, senza sacrificio non c'è <em>disciplina</em>, senza disciplina non c'è <em>risultato</em>.</h2>
      <div class="main-button scroll-to-section">
        <a href="#features">Prenota la tua prova</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to post your relevant HTML code too

Comment: Done, my fault !

Comment: as sidenote: `min-width: 100%; min-height: 100vh; max-width: 100%; max-height: 100vh;` is an inefficient declaration. Just use: `width: 100%; height: 100vh;` which is exactly the same.

Comment: If you need a CSS rule that only applies on small screens you can look into `@media` queries for CSS.